# Proxied filter value for database-backed input field

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

### Background

For the country field, the system detects and defaults to Canada. For the city field, the user types a Canadian city name, populated [Facebook-style](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/).

Both the country list and city list are populated using AJAX and JSON, sourced from a remote database using a proxy (queried via PHP).

The country is defaulted to the user's country of origin using [MaxMind's GeoIP PHP API](http://www.maxmind.com/app/php).

When the user selects a different country, its two-letter ISO code must be passed as a parameter to the city input so that the query that drives it can search for cities in the selected country.

For example, a user whose IP address is in Canada can choose the United States. When this happens:

1. the city field will be erased;
2. the city field gains focus; and then
3. only U.S. cities are displayed (as the user types).

### Problem

The following PHP snippet proxies retrieval of the city list to a remote server:

```
echo file_get_contents( 'http://server/city.dhtml?q=' . 
  urlencode( $_GET['q'] ) );
```

The jQuery tokenInput function does not seem to provide a mechanism to pass additional content. The relevant jQuery snippets follow.

#### Acquire Countries

The following code gets a country code and a list of countries. It sets the user's country as the default country.

```
  // Where in the world?
  $.getJSON( 'geoip.dhtml', function( data ) {
    country = data[0].id;
  });

  // Select from countries that have significant amounts of data.
  $.getJSON( 'country.dhtml', function( data ) {
    var h = '';
    var len = data.length;

    for( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
      var s = '';

      // Make the person's own country the default selection.
      if( data[i].id == country ) {
        s = '" selected="selected"';
      }

      h += '<option value="' + data[i].id + s + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>';
    }

    $('#country').html(h);
  });
```

#### Acquire Cities

The following code downloads the list of cities. The `tokenInput` function automatically passes the `q` parameter to the code inside the "local version" of `city.dhtml` (the PHP source code snippet is shown above). The `q` parameter is the text that the user types for the city.

```
  $('#city').tokenInput( 'city.dhtml', {
    hintText: "Type a city name.",
    tokenLimit: 1,
    classes: {
      tokenList: "token-input-list-facebook",
      token: "token-input-token-facebook",
      tokenDelete: "token-input-delete-token-facebook",
      selectedToken: "token-input-selected-token-facebook",
      highlightedToken: "token-input-highlighted-token-facebook",
      dropdown: "token-input-dropdown-facebook",
      dropdownItem: "token-input-dropdown-item-facebook",
      dropdownItem2: "token-input-dropdown-item2-facebook",
      selectedDropdownItem: "token-input-selected-dropdown-item-facebook",
      inputToken: "token-input-input-token-facebook"
    }
  });
```

The `city.dhtml` must to filter the cities by country code.

### Question

How would you provide the country code to `city.dhtml`, without using a cookie?

### Ideas

The latest version of the token input supports JSONP, would that be useful?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `tokenInput` URL parameter cannot be changed once the input has been set. While perhaps possible to delete the existing `tokenInput` and recreate it each time a new country is selected, the solution would be a hack.

The solution is to use a patch for the jQuery TokenInput that allows setting the URL parameter based on the result from a function call.

https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/pull/77

Apply the patch and use the following code to change the query dynamically:

```
  function cityURL() {
    return 'city.dhtml?c=' + $('#country').val();
  }

  $('#city').tokenInput( cityURL, { /* ... */ });
```

And disable caching in `jquery.tokeninput.js` (near line 650):

```
    //var cached_results = cache.get(query);
    var cached_results = false;
```

Comment: @Dave Without setting cached_results = false in .net it's worked too, Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 1):

Neat question, +1! What's keeping you from just doing:

```
$('#city').tokenInput('city.dhtml?c=' + $('#country').val(), { /* ... */ });
```

You probably need to enclose that within a `onChange` event, but it should work.

Comment: @Alix: Thanks for the note. I considered something similar, but expected it would translate to `city.dhtml?q=CA?q=vancouver` (when the user types "vancouver"). Can be parsed, but feels hackish.

Comment: @Dave Jarvis: Oh, sorry about that. Missed the part where you mentioned the `q` parameter was being used for the input (it's getting late :P). Why not use another identifier, like `&c=`?

Comment: @Alix: This still likely yields `city.dhtml?c=CA?q=vancouver`, rather than `city.dhtml?c=CA&q=vancouver`.

Comment: @Dave: Humm... Are you sure? https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/blob/master/src/jquery.tokeninput.js#L651 seems to take that into consideration.

Comment: @Alix: Unfortunately, this leads to duplicated input fields, due to the way `tokenInput` works. There is a patch that contains a fix for this issue.